# Why is this named anonymous js function working before it is defined?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple `Gulpfile` with a task defined.  There is a named anonymous function that is defined after the `Gulp` task.  The task uses this function and is working when I would expect to get `undefined is not a function`, but I am not.  Here is the code:

```
gulp.task('bower', function() {
  var bowerDir = 'bower_components';
  fs.readdir(bowerDir, function(err, dirs) {
    _.each(dirs, function(dir) {
      var directory = dir;
      fs.stat(path.join(bowerDir, dir), function(err, stats) {
        if(stats.isDirectory()) {
          listing('bower_components');
        }
      });
    });
  });
});

var listing = function(dir) {
  console.log(dir);
};
```

Please explain why this is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gulp.task()`, `fs.readdir()` and `fs.stat()` are all asynchronous functions.  They call their callback functions sometime LATER, not immediately.  That means that the code after that defines `listing` gets a chance to run BEFORE the callback is actually called.  So, thus `listing` is defined before it is actually used.

I wouldn't suggest this as a good coding method myself because you are relying on the timing on things.

---

If, instead you defined your `listing` function like this:

```
function listing(dir) {
  console.log(dir);
}
```

Then, you would not have a dependency on timing because all statically defined functions like this are parsed first and hoisted to the top of the scope they are defined in and thus always available in that scope ragardless of timing.

---

FYI, if you really want to show this to yourself, you can add this logging to see the actual timing and sequence of things:

```
function logTime(msg) {
    console.log((new Date()).getTime() + ": " + msg);
}

logTime("start");
gulp.task('bower', function() {
  var bowerDir = 'bower_components';
  fs.readdir(bowerDir, function(err, dirs) {
    _.each(dirs, function(dir) {
      var directory = dir;
      fs.stat(path.join(bowerDir, dir), function(err, stats) {
        if(stats.isDirectory()) {
          logTime("about to call listing()");
          listing('bower_components');
        }
      });
    });
  });
});

logTime("about to define listing");
var listing = function(dir) {
  logTime("listing() called");
  console.log(dir);
};
```

Comment: I ran the code that you sent across.  I am not sure that it is a timing issue.  Could it be that `listing` is used in a closure?  It seems that the js interpreter scans the file, but does not execute the gulp task.  When that happens, `listing` is in a closure that isn't called until later, at which time it has already been defined.  So in a sense it is a timing issue, but it will never have a `function not defined` error.  You could be right, but I just am trying to fully understand this and wanted to get another point of view.

Comment: @jhamm - do you understand what asynchronous functions are?  That is the key here.  This has nothing to do with a closure.  It's purely about the timing of when asynchronous callbacks are actually called.  An asynchronous function starts it's operation and then returns and other JS immediately after it runs.  Then, sometime LATER, when the results arrive from the asynchronous operation, the asynchronous function calls its callback.

Answer (score 0):

Because that annonymous function is a callback function and most likely is called after the initialization of listing function.